# How to compute the prediction variance from Relevance Vector Machine regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

I am using a [relevance vector machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_vector_machine) in R, [rvm()](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/kernlab/html/rvm.html), to solve a regression problem. I need to know the variance of the fitted values for each identified RVs. Does anyone know how to program to compute the prediction variances with R's [Kernlab package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html)?